# Is there a security risk in placing a csrf token as a query parameter in the URL upon submission?

Tags: authentication, httprequest, csrf, csrf-protection

Many of my forms are submitted as `multipart/form-data` that on my sever are parsed in streams and it is all asynchronous. It would be a pain to wait for the csrf token, receive it and then reject it, meanwhile some of the form has already been processed. Therefore I find it a lot easier to just set it as a query variable on the form upon submission. I will still pass it as a hidden form value when the user requests the page. Is there a risk to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a CSRF token can be done using any means as long as it is not solely just cookies.

As long as you're redirecting after processing the form, this would prevent your CSRF token being leaked in the `referer` header.

Note that your token may still be leaked in browser history, proxy and server logs as default, which would not be the case with POST data. However, if you're regenerating the CSRF token per session then this should limit exposure.